# How do I find the road distance between two locations?

Tags: here-api

I am using HERE Developer API key. I want to calculate the road distance between 2 lats & longs. Can anybody help me on this with PHP code.

Comment: add the codes you have tried so it can help to know exact error

Answer (score 0):

When using the Routing API, if you ask for summary or travelSummary in the result, you get a `length` result which is in meter. For example:

```
"travelSummary": {
    "duration": 20973,
    "length": 619962,
    "baseDuration": 20316
},
```